# Updating a Drupal Site and all I have is a HostGator login

Tags: html, drupal, hosting

As a favor for a friend, I'm trying to add a quick Valentine's Ad for an article that is supposed to be appended to the top of their existing site starting... tomorrow. They have an existing site made by somebody they are no longer in contact with back in 2010 built with Drupal.

I don't know Drupal. The only information I have is a HostGator login that I'm currently using to send a backup zip to my email.

HostGator's File menu doesn't even show search results for the text I'm searching for on the main page where I'd put this.

I have no idea what I'm doing, basically. I'm comfortable as a web developer in general and figured "yeah I can add a thing to the top of your pages, sure." I can write that HTML quickly, but everything else... do I need Drupal installed, etc, and will that run with the backup that HostGator is gonna send me?

Any advice? I realize I'm an idiot for signing up for a favor like this last minute.

Ultimately I just need to add some pictures and some text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to achieve this would be creating custom block. Not sure what version of Drupal you use, but let's assume it's D7 (similar for other versions):

1. Go to Structure -> Blocks -> Add block
2. Enter your static content into "Block body" field. Change that field format to "full html" so drupal won't filter out some of your tags.
3. If you don't want Drupal's block title to appear in Block title field enter < none > (without space signs in between! - SO can't show it without spaces).
4. Save your block
5. Now go to Structure -> Blocks...your block should be visible in block list. You can find and edit it from there.
6. Theme site uses has "Regions" (something like sidebars). If want your block to appear with main content find your block and select "Content" region. Or any other you want.
7. At top of that page should be a link "Demonstrate block regions" - click it to see which region is where..
8. After selecting region you can click "configure" link for your block to precise in what conditions block should appear on page. Click it.
9. Scroll down and in right sidebar at bottom of configure page you'll see "Pages", "Content types"... it for selecting on what pages, on what content types...your block should be visible. Default is everywhere, so if you need this - use it.
10. Save block. If you didn't save on Structure -> Block after selecting region select region again and Save.
11. You can embed your CSS there, but you can also go to (usually): /sites/all/themes/your_theme/styles/style.css or something like that.
12. If you can't find CSS turn the caching off for a moment: Configuration -> Development -> Performance and inspect location of loaded CSS file(s) (use browser inspection tool).

Good luck!

Comment: Much appreciated. This is just an old Drupal site that I'm able to get a zip of via HostGator so... let's hope it builds and stuff once the backup is emailed (apparently takes hours). I'll have to try to figure out the environment too. Anyway, this should be really helpful. I'll have to continue to investigate a bit but I'm really glad you answered. Hopefully I can get this done in time. Honestly I thought I was gonna just be adding a few divs of HTML. So it goes.

Comment: I tried to answer ASAP, partly because you are short with time, but partly before other guys start asking "show us some effort" or even close your question. Glad that I helped.

Comment: I'm glad you answered anyway. I can't show effort since the site is still downloading, and I really needed help. I was pretty stressed out. Glad you came through for me. I'll still have to piece this together soon, but at least I have some steps to follow.

Comment: In case you don't have administrative privileges to sign into the backend of the Drupal site (after downloading locally for testing), you can install the command line add-on package, Drush [https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/] and use the drush uli command to bypass knowing the password to login.  If the original admin account is disabled, you may need to reenable it by changing its status in the "users" table of the mysql database; alternatively you can use drush uli [username] to login as another user with admin privileges.